# How Can open subscription settings with code in TVOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos, apple-tv

I am trying to open the cancel subscribe screen in TVOS but can't find it.

The below code working perfectly with the iOS app. I need to open this screen with TV side.

```
try await StoreKit.AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)!)
```